# Adding a Service Reference to an AXIS Service

Tags: c#, .net, service, reference, axis

I need to add a service Reference to an Axis Service like this one : https://api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcSession

Somehow it can't be added because

"There was an error downloading 'https://api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcSession/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found."

Why can I access the Service via http adress in my browser but the Wizard in VS2010 can't find the needed data ?

Anyone can help me what am I doin wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [?WSDL postfix](https://api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcSession?WSDL) for such links